# Jfreechart scatter plot with categories

Tags: java, jfreechart

i need to plot a scatter plot but with categories like all points in class a category should be red or the point shape can be a square anything to distinguish it from class b points but i also dont want the points to be joined by lines as in XYPlot. I have searched for it and couldnt find the answer, so if you find this as a duplicate question then please direct me to original one. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Why not to use the JavaFX plotting libraries?

Comment: i have tried this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/jfreechart_xy_chart.htm and it almost satisfies my need but the thing is i dont want lines connecting the points but i do want points from different data sets to be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

i played with scatter plot and was able to solve the problem. the following code solves it. setupData() takes the class name as input and basically categories it. I failed to see that earlier. I hope it helps guys facing same issue.

```
package graph.generator;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;

public class GenerateScatterPlot extends ApplicationFrame{

    static XYSeriesCollection dataset;

    public GenerateScatterPlot(String applicationTitle) {
        super(applicationTitle);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Coordinates", "X", "Y", setupData(), PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false); 
        NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
        chartPanel.setVerticalAxisTrace(true);
        chartPanel.setHorizontalAxisTrace(true);
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    public static XYDataset setupData() {
        return dataset;
    }

    public static void addToSet(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> coordinates, String classOfData)
    {
        if(dataset == null)
        {
            dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        }

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(classOfData);
        for (ArrayList<Double> arrayList : coordinates) {
            series.add(arrayList.get(0),arrayList.get(1));
        }

        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
}
```